# Is it possible to record/track the search history of intelliJ IDE editor?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am trying to create a class that can find all the searches made in the IntelliJ editor when users use the command F prompt and search for whatever they are currently looking for. I was thinking of using a listener that would record their input , however I don't know how I would use a listener on the search bar? Any suggestions? Do you think its plausible? Thank you.

Comment: Please use https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development for the plug-in development questions.

Answer (score 0):

What for? If you type ⌘F to open the search bar in an editor (I am using Mac shortcuts, probably ctrl-F on Windows), there is a magnifying glass symbol on the left which will open a popup with the previous searches. Or when the focus is in the search bar, you can use ⌥-down (alt-down) to open the dropdown of previous searches.

Comment: Yes, I know that is a way to do it manually, however I wanted to build a class to do it automatically so that I could use those search results in an algorithm. Otherwise the user of my plugin would have to input their search results and that is not what I am looking for. Thanks for your answer though!